# add days to a date in a for-loop javascript

Tags: javascript, date, for-loop, addition, days

My problem is:

I want to go through an array, which has numbers in it.
For each number I want to add this number as days to a certain
date:

```
var days= ["1", "3", "4"];

$.each(days, function(key,value){

    var start = new Date(2015,01,08);

    var nextDay = new Date(start);

    console.log("start-day is:"+nextDay+ " and I should add "+value+" days");

    nextDay.setDate(start.getDate()+value);

    console.log("The next day is:"+nextDay);

});
```

The start-date is the 8th. of February. 
if the value is 1, the last log should be: "The next day is: Monday 09. February...."
But the log says something like 22.April and it even changes the timezone....

If i just run it once, the  result is correct (9. February).
It just doesn't work in the foor loop.
(I'm new to javascript)

anybody an idea? 
Thanks in advance, Sebi from Germany

Comment: Sorry, the first line should be: var days= [1, 2, 4];

Comment: Note that you can edit your question whenever you need, but don't edit it to add the solution: we need the original question!

Comment: After your edition the code seems right: I see "The next day is:Thu Feb 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Romance Standard Time)"

Comment: Thank you, It was my mistake, I really had strings in the array and not numbers -.- sorry and thank you! should i delete the question?

Comment: In my opinion you have two options: delete it if you think it does not add anything to the site,... or edit it adding the error again and select an answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in an array of strings not integers so you are actually adding a string to a date. There are two options

**Better Option**

Pass in an array of integers not an array of strings

```
var days= [1,3,4]; // This is an array of integers

$.each(days, function(key,value){

    var start = new Date(2015,01,08);

    var nextDay = new Date(start);

    console.log("start-day is:"+nextDay+ " and I should add "+value+" days");

    nextDay.setDate(start.getDate()+value);

    console.log("The next day is:"+nextDay);

});
```

**Worse Option**

You can `parseInt()` your array or make your array numbers just before you add it to the start date.

```
var days= ["1", "3", "4"]; // These are strings not integers

$.each(days, function(key,value){

    var start = new Date(2015,01,08);

    var nextDay = new Date(start);

    console.log("start-day is:"+nextDay+ " and I should add "+value+" days");

    nextDay.setDate(start.getDate()+parseInt(value)); // Strings are converted to integers here

    console.log("The next day is:"+nextDay);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

The days are defined as strings and not numbers. If you change them to numbers it should work:

```
var days= [1, 3, 4];
```